# How to truncate and add new rows to the table with a select query never getting empty results

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a requirement where a table holds the state of certain things.
This table is truncated and new status data in inserted in it every second.
The problem is that if a select query is executed between a delete and the following insert, the user will get empty table in return.
SQL Transactions would not help here i think but not sure.
Also, if the select query is executed between the delete and insert query, it shouldn't return error because its blocked by a database lock. it should just wait till the delete + insert operation is finished.

What would be the best way to implement such a system?
How should i form the "delete + insert" query and the "select" query?

Thank you in advance.

--------additional information
This table would be result of a multiple heavy queries and will be updated every second so that the applications do not run those heavy queries and instead, they would get the required information from this table.
so a truncate and insert every second and multiple selects at random.

Comment: Why do you think transactions wouldn't help here?

Comment: Begin a transaction, truncate, insert new rows, and finally commit.

Comment: because from what i understand, the data can be read between delete and insert inside a transaction. transaction would allow me to treat a list of sql actions as one just to be able to revert it but otherwise, other query can read dirty data according to my understanding. also, it shouldnt make the other select query fail. am i wrong in my understanding of transactions?

Comment: hi dan & Aaron. i think transaction is the best way to do it like you said. i did some more testing and so far it seems to be  working well. we are however going with a different approach but i think transaction solution serves best for what i needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't truncate the table.  Instead, insert the new status using an identity primary key or the date as the primary key.  Then do:

```
select top 1 date
from table
order by date desc
```

or

```
select max(date)
from table
```

(These should have basically the same execution plan.)

Then, you insert the new date.  When the insert is done, the data is immediately available.

You can then delete older rows at your leisure.

Comment: i am not getting date from the table. i am selecting the entire table. I had said status data which you seemed to have misunderstood as status date.

Comment: @user3754372 . . . Actually not.  Just keep inserting records and pull the last record using an index on a `datetime` column or on an identity column.  You will no longer have the race condition, and you don't even have to start messing with transactions.

Comment: it happens every second(i modified question to help you understand the scenario better) and if i dont truncate, the table will be huge and even if i delete the old rows everytime, my primary key will  be very big. do you still think its the best alternative? 
I am more trying to understand how the sql can be used for locking to achieve this task. What you mentioned is my backup plan if i cant find other solution.

Comment: I vote for Gordon's suggestion, except just use the timestamp as the primary key. Schedule a task early each day to delete the previous day's entries. That way it won't grow very large. You can even create a view that just exposes the latest entry (with or without the timestamp) so your developers don't have to change their queries (rename the table, create the view with the same name). In fact, the new rows can be inserted through the view so all you would have to do is remove the `truncate` statement and create the daily task.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, this table always contains only one row, the last status change. The contents changes about every second, apparently 24 hours a day.

Rather than change the data with a truncate/insert pair of operations, why not just update the one row? One operation, no race condition, no locking conflicts at all.

There is even a way to do that without changing any existing code:

- Rename the table
- Create a view which shows the row from the renamed table. Name it the original table name.
- Create an "instead of insert" trigger on the view. The trigger performs an update to the table rather than an insert. This could be performed with a merge statement which will work if the table should ever happen to be empty.

Oops, I was wrong. You would still have to change the code to remove the truncate statement. It will not work against the view but it will throw an exception. Unfortunately, you can't intercept the truncate with a trigger and simply ignore it.

Then when the insert is executed, a truncate is no longer necessary and the insert converted into an update (or merge). One operation.

Comment: it doesnt insert just 1 row. i dont know where i mentioned that it inserts one row but if i did then thats not the case. it inserts from 0 to 500 rows depending on the time of day.